# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at eval

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have imported the jQuery in main.js file but still it throws this error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at eval (navbar.js)`

I am unable to fix this. I tried every possible way to import in main.js

I used the jQuery CDN link in the `public/index.html` file, this error is gone but the navbar script which is present inside the `navbar.js` file does not work at all.

Installed jquery using npm  `npm install jquery --save`

`navbar.js`

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    if ($.fn.kanglaNav) {
        $('#bigNavBar').kanglaNav();
    }

    $(".kangla-navbar-toggler").on("click", function () {
        $(".top-header").toggleClass("z-index-reduce");
    });

})(jQuery);
```

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './assets/css/style.css'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './assets/css/kangla-nav.min.css'
import './assets/css/animate.css'
import '../node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/magnific-popup.css'
import './assets/js/popper.min.js'
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
import './assets/js/kangla-nav.min.js'
import '../node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js'
import './assets/js/navbar.js'

const { $, jQuery } = require('jquery')
window.$ = $
window.jQuery = jQuery

new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: It's unknown what is your setup and how scripts are loaded. The error means that main.js wasn't evaluated at the time when navbar.js runs.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have added the complete main.js file. please have a look at it and provide me your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` global variable is undefined at the time when it's accessed because `import './assets/js/navbar.js'` line is evaluated before `window.jQuery = jQuery`. `jquery` doesn't contain `$`, etc exports, global variables will be `undefined` any way.

Moving `jQuery` assignment above `import` would be incorrect because import statements are hoisted by specs.

A way to fix this is to move `window.jQuery = jQuery` to `jquery.js` and import it before modules that depend on it.

A more correct way is to not rely on globals in modular environment and import them in modules that depend on them:

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Comment: thanks, it worked when imported in required js files